# Unusual renewal of subscription products

Tags: ubercart, notifications

Marketing wants to sell a subscription product at a discounted price of 5 septims a year for 3 years, and then return it to its regular price of 10 septims after that.

In discussion the idea came up to:

- Generate 3 new products (SUB_Y1, SUB_Y2, and SUB_Y3 in addition to the existing SUB product)
- Set up the renewals notifications for the first 3 products to encourage users to renew
- Direct them only to the next product in the series
- Offer them the regular product after the first 3 cheap years

However, I know my marketing department; if I do this, they will want more, and by the end of the year I will have 25 different series, each of which having 2 to 5 steps in the process. My /admin/store/products/view will be a nightmare to behold.

Is there a cleaner way of handling this that will not use up much of the 25 minutes actual coding time I am alotted each week?

Comment: The possible solution I just realized... which may or may not work depending on the complexity of the mod:

I am going to look at extending the "After first recurring expiration" functionality... so "After THIRD recurring expiration" then it would redirect to the regular product.

This may be biting off more than I can chew... but its where I'm going at the moment.

Comment: Ok realized after the fact that the "first expiration" code is part of a custom module... which is likely derived from another module that I'll contrib my changes with if I get that far.

Comment: Really Kiamlaluno? Bored much? You changed the Title from Title Case to sentence case... the title... sigh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I altered the custom module with a toggle to extend the "different price after first month" to 1,3,6, or 12 months, and attach that to the product.  Given that the module was outdated custom variant of a Ubercart mod in the first place, there was nothing to contrib to.  Solution worked very well though, if anyone bumps into it.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used [UC Recurring Payments and Subscriptions](http://drupal.org/project/uc_recurring) before properly, but if each payment is a fully fledged order then I imagine you could use Conditional Actions to look at the date compared to the initial purchase date and give a discount if that is within the three years. The coding effort is then just creating a new condition using [hook_ca_condition()](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/hook_ca_condition) which is not hard, and then after that setting up the pricing rules in the CA interface.

Comment: Clever... that may work if my current course of action explodes in my face.